# Extracting text under a certain section from a source code of a url using BeautifulSoup in python

Tags: python, html, url, beautifulsoup, scrape

I'm a beginner in python and don't really have any experience with HTML. I just saw a youtube video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEItYHtqQUg&ab_channel=edureka%21) about web scraping and got interested in extracting texts from a URL in python.

I tried to practice it links from a random database. This is the URL and code I used
https://rtk.rjifuture.org/rmp/facility/100000028301

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen

url = "https://rtk.rjifuture.org/rmp/facility/100000028301"
html = urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
type(soup)

all_links = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'col'})
str_cells = str(all_links)
cleartext = BeautifulSoup(str_cells, "html.parser").get_text().split(',')
```

Let's say I want to extract the Address under Location. By using the code above, I could just get the address by doing `print(cleartext[7])`

But then when I tried the same thing with another link in the same database like https://rtk.rjifuture.org/rmp/facility/100000083214,
it didn't work as well as the first part of the webpage (The section right under the name of the facility) was structured slightly differently. This also didn't work well when there was a , in one of the data before the address.

Is there a way to target the Address under the Location section and extract the text from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For URL 1 you can first find all div based on class given and find index based on that find location div and extract data using `get_text()` method

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res=requests.get("https://rtk.rjifuture.org/rmp/facility/100000028301")
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
 

soup.find_all("div",class_="container-fluid rmp-section")[1].find("div",class_="col").get_text(strip=True)
```

**Output:**

```
'308 Timmons StreetSnow Hill, MD 21863'
```

URL 2:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
res=requests.get("https://rtk.rjifuture.org/rmp/facility/100000083214")
soup=BeautifulSoup(res.text,"html.parser")
soup.find_all("div",class_="container-fluid rmp-section")[1].find("div",class_="col").get_text(strip=True)
```

**Output:**

```
'2.5 miles E of Hwy 59 on Co. Rd VKit Carson, CO 80825'
```

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I want. May I ask why `find("div",class_="col")` this part finds the address? I can see there are a lot of "col" under "container-fluid rmp-section")[1] and couldn't quite figure out how it just returns the address. I guess to make it more specific, what should I do if I want to extract the text next to "Description" which is "Center of Facility"?

Comment: See what it does first find all div based on `container-fluid rmp-section` this class in which returns list of elements in which we find 1 index which contains all data of location and then we go for `find` method which find element based on class `col`  and find method always returns first matching element

Comment: Oh I got it. I guess I should use `find_all` to find other info in the section. Thanks!